# magento 2 Add custom field in cart Estimate Shipping and Tax

Tags: magento2

I want to remove the state field from cart page and add the new field with autocomplete.
I want to add code like
file - vendor/Block/Cart/LayoutProcessor.php
code

```
$elements = [
            'city' => [
                'visible' => $this->isCityActive(),
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'label' => __('City'),
                'value' =>  null
            ],
            'country_id' => [
                'visible' => true,  //Remove the country
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('Country'),
                'options' => [],
                'value' => null
            ],
            'region_id' => [
                'visible' => false,  //Remove the state
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('State/Province'),
                'options' => [],
                'value' => null
            ],
            'postcode' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
                'value' => null
            ],
            'td_postcode' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
                'value' => null
            ]
        ];


        if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
            'country_id' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(),
            'region_id' => $this->regionCollection->addAllowedCountriesFilter()->toOptionArray(),
            ];
        }

        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
            ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
            ) {
            $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
        ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
            $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
            $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
        }
        return $jsLayout;
```

Comment: Which fields do you want to remove? like  Country,  City, State/Province etc.

Comment: I want to remove country and state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite this file: Vendor\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor.php

First create the `registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendorname_Mymodule',
    __DIR__
);
```

Then create `app/code/Vendor/Mymodule/etc/di.xml`
Add following code in this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor" type="Vendorname\Mymodule\Block\Preference\Cart\LayoutProcessor"/>

</config>
```

Now create `Vendorname\Mymodule\Block\Preference\Cart\LayoutProcessor.php`

Add following code in this file:

```
<?php



namespace Vendorname\Mymodule\Block\Preference\Cart;


class LayoutProcessor extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor {


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $merger, 
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $countryCollection, 
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection $regionCollection
    ) {
        $this->merger = $merger;
        $this->countryCollection = $countryCollection;
        $this->regionCollection = $regionCollection;
         parent::__construct($merger, $countryCollection, $regionCollection);
    }


    /**
     * Process js Layout of block
     *
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
       $elements = [
        'city' => [
            'visible' => $this->isCityActive(),
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'value' =>  null
        ],
        'country_id' => [
            'visible' => false,  //Remove the country
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('Country'),
            'options' => [],
            'value' => null
        ],
        'region_id' => [
            'visible' => false,  //Remove the state
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('State/Province'),
            'options' => [],
            'value' => null
        ],
        'postcode' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
            'value' => null
        ]
    ];

      if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
                'country_id' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(),
                'region_id' => $this->regionCollection->addAllowedCountriesFilter()->toOptionArray(),
            ];
        }

        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
            ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
        ) {
            $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
            ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
            $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
            $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Change `'visible' => false`  for removing the field.

Comment: Do you want add new custom field as well?

Comment: yes, but after adding this code no shipping methods are refreshed

Comment: Have you run all these commands: php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I tried it but "region" field not remove

Comment: ok, I will suggest to hide the field from CSS, because shipping calculation depends on the country and region.  Check this file, which is creating problem: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/post-code.js

Comment: But I am creating extension and this is not good to hide using css, no other way to hide only region?

Comment: @Priya Have you got solution for this one?