# Magento 2 handling custom field in Estimate Shipping and Tax block

Tags: magento2, cart

I would like to know how to handle custom fields in Estimate Shipping and Tax block with help of this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221725/magento-2-add-custom-field-in-cart-estimate-shipping-and-tax). I updated block with custom field(radio button) but I'm not sure how to handle custom field as extension attribute.

I  tried with this [stack exchange answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135969/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-and-then-send-it), which shows how to handle custom field in shipping information. but it doesn't help me, as I'm not sure which actions should be used for Estimation and I don't find any documentation on handling new field in Estimate Shipping and Tax block.

Can some one guide me on this ?

Mockup:
[image]

Comment: Hello @pkrishna, have you got the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Every Carrier has it own rule to to refresh rates based on the changes like postcode, country

For example, the FedEx shipping method requires only two fields of the shipping address to be filled: Country, Zip Code, and City. You can refer validation rules for Carrier from here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html

Comment: We have requirement to handle custom field for Shipping estimation in cart page, What you have shared is about shipping information for checkout page. And the documentation deals about validation not about handling custom field